# rotation of spherical harmonics using Wigner D-matrix

Tags: special-functions, rotation

A very stupid question as I am very confused:
I have a surface charge density which is a function of spherical harmonics $\sigma_{l,m}=Y_{lm}$ (only the real part). Now I need to rotate the particle, or rotate the surface charge, using the Euler angles.
How can I properly rotate spherical harmonics using Wigner D-matrix in Mathematica?

As stated here in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix#Relation_to_spherical_harmonics_and_Legendre_polynomials

should I set the second index (here $m_0$, where we have summation over it) to zero to make the Wigner matrix proportional to the spherical harmonics?
something like this:

```
σ0 = (Sqrt[(4 π)/(2 l + 1)]  )^-1  
 σlm[l_,m_] := σ0  Sum[WignerD[{l, -m0, -m}, α1, β1, γ1] , {m0, 0, 0}]
```

or should I keep it general:

```
σ0 = (Sqrt[(4 π)/(2 l + 1)]  )^-1  
 σlm[l_,m_] := σ0  Sum[WignerD[{l, -m0, -m}, α1, β1, γ1] , {m0, -l, l}]
```

Suppose I would like to rotate $\sigma_{l,m}=Y_{21}$, which one is it the correct way of rotation?

Comment: For reasons unclear to me, `WignerD[]` is using a different convention for the Euler angles. In any event, corresponding to the notation in Wiki, $D_{l,m}^j(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ is `WignerD[{j, l, m}, -α, -β, -γ]`, and $d_{l,m}^j(\beta)$ is `WignerD[{j, l, m}, -β]`. [This](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WignerD.html#10003570) gives the relation between `SphericalHarmonicY[]` and `WignerD[]`.

Comment: @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties, Thank you so much for your reply. I think your comment have some "technical difficulties" ;) 
Are there any differences, in Mathematica, between making the $m$ values in Wigner matrix negative or making the Euler angles negative? Do you mean for rotating the spherical harmonics using Mathematica, I always should set the $m_0=0$ in Wigner matrix? I think I can understand the process on paper, but Mathematica is different.

Comment: * I mean making $m$ and $l$ values negative and in second part, $m_0=l=0$